# swipeable tab layout for switching between FragmentActivity and not Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I recently made an android app where activities were extending FragmentActivity class. Now I am redesigning my app and putting the swipable tab layout to switch between various layouts. Now the catch is the swipable tab layout works only with class that extend Fragment and not Fragment Activity (as per my knowledge).

Also if I make my class to extend Fragment in place of fragmentActivity then I am restricted to use some methods which are necessary for my app.

So Can anyone suggest what to do in such scenario where I want to swipe between FragmentActivity class and not Fragment

Comment: You can use viewpager

Comment: Keshav I am already using ViewPager. But isnt it to view fragments?

Comment: Use viewpagerindicator library http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Keshav I went through the website u suggested. but it seems that they are also navigating between fragments and not activities. I want to navigate between activities. any idea? thanks

Comment: Why in activity ? I thinks its hard to do with activities.

Comment: Thats the problem, I have done all my implementation in activies. and now to do it in fragment is pretty hectic and also i wont be able to achieve all the funtionality... any suggestion what should i do now?

Comment: You can do anything in fragment which you are doing in activities.

Comment: I tried that by converting my class extending Fragment instead of FragmentActivity. But I get a lot of errors.

Comment: @keshav thanks. It was probably my ignorance that i thought I cant acheieve my functionalities in a fragment. I was wrong. A little code walk thorugh did the trick. thanks.